# view the count of total results

Tags: php, arrays, string, codeigniter

my total counts results looks like this now i want to echo it to get the display but its not getting

[image]

this is my controller

```
  $data['present']= $this->attendance_model->present_report_by_empid($v_employee->user_id,$date);

  $data['presentss']=explode(',',$data['present']);
```

this is my view

```
 <?php  echo $presentss;?>
```

this is my model

```
public function present_report_by_empid($user_id = null,$date = null) 
 {


   $temp = explode("-",$date);
   $query='tbl_attendance.date_in';
   $this->db->where('tbl_attendance.attendance_status', 1);
   $this->db->where('tbl_attendance.user_id', $user_id);
   $this->db->where("YEAR(tbl_attendance.date_in)",$temp[0]);
   $this->db->where("MONTH(tbl_attendance.date_in)",$temp[1]);
   $count=$this->db->count_all_results('tbl_attendance');

   return $count;
}
```

when i change my code like this

```
 $data['present'][]= $this->attendance_model->present_report_by_empid($v_employee->user_id,$date);
```

and view as

```
  <?php foreach($present as $pe =>$p){?>
                                    <?php echo $p;?>
                                    <?php }?>
```

i got like this [image]

but i want it like this [image]

please help to me to solve

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Please explain concretely what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you show more codes ?? as you are using `echo $presentss` but never defined as much as i can see

Comment: Share your model file code as well

Comment: i had added the model

Comment: can you show where you defined $presentss

Comment: @PaulRoefs see in my controller

Comment: @user_777 so $data['presentss']  is an array with count values which you want sum?

Comment: when  i gave var_dump($data['presentss']) am getting the results shown above in the image and i want that to be shown in the display

Comment: i dont want to sum that i want to echo that in the same order

Comment: what result are you getting now?

Comment: am getting all as zero

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this:

```
  $data['presentss']=explode(',',$data['present']);
```

Your number of rows is already in

```
<?php echo $presents;?>
```

You can try to use to check your query:

```
  echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Also switch to check the returned rows as well as the count:

```
$this->db->num_rows();
```

Comment: yaa but when i echo that in the view page am getting all as `0`

Comment: Then that's what the number of returned rows is.

Comment: You can try $this->db->last_query(); to check your query is correct and run it in phpmyadmin for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.Use `$this->db->num_rows()`to count total number of rows.

**Model**

```
public function present_report_by_empid($user_id = null,$date = null) 
 {


   $temp = explode("-",$date);
   $query='tbl_attendance.date_in';
   $this->db->where('tbl_attendance.attendance_status', 1);
   $this->db->where('tbl_attendance.user_id', $user_id);
   $this->db->where("YEAR(tbl_attendance.date_in)",$temp[0]);
   $this->db->where("MONTH(tbl_attendance.date_in)",$temp[1]);
   $result = $this->db->get('tbl_attendance')->result_array();
   $count=count($result); //counts number of rows
   return $count;
}
```

**Controller**:

```
$data['present']= $this->attendance_model->present_report_by_empid($v_employee->user_id,$date);
```

And

In **View**

```
<?php  echo $present;?>
```

Comment: when i used your code i got like this `Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::num_rows()`

Comment: sorry for late repaly @Hek mat..still i didnt get the correct result but what i got is pasted on above please see